# How do you find a table using capybara with no ID

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am using Capybara to do some testing on a website which has a table on it that holds a variable amount of data and is generated by google visualisation. The table has no ID value and I have been told there is no way of putting an ID field in.

Is there any other way to find a table and then be able to pull in and look through the data in the table in capybara/ruby? I know what data should be in the table and want to check that it is displaying the correct results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use xpath:

```
find(:xpath, "//table/tr")
```

Or standard finders a la jQuery:

```
find("table")
```

Sidenote, remember you can chain `find` calls.

---

Since you've a class, use it!

```
find(".class_name")
find(".google-visualization-table-table")
```

Comment: I've tried then and they both come back with "Unable to find". The only tags in the HTML are a Class, Cell spacing and style if that helps. Most of the time there are 2 column headings that say "Platform" and "Number of Users".

Comment: the xpath should work, it's even in the doc, but to use it, check that it gives the proper path. Is there any wrapping div? what's your original html?

Comment: its is now returning #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x2ff7498> the html is:

Comment: <divid="table_div">
<divstyle="position: relative; ">
<divstyle="position: relative; ">
<tableclass="google-visualization-table-table"cellspacing="0"style="width: 785px; ">
<tbody>
<trclass="google-visualization-table-tr-head">
<tdclass="google-visualization-table-th">Platform</td>
<tdclass="google-visualization-table-th">NumberofUsers</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: using find(".google-visualization-table-table") returns #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x2e8e208>

Comment: Yes so it's found. Your question is answered!

Comment: If you want to check the content etc... See the capybara api. Please don't forget to marker the question as solved and feel free to ask anither question if you need.

Comment: oh, i think i get it now, it is just telling me it has found it, and i should use something like .value or .text to actually find what it says? thanks guys :)